# Magento 2 : Remove products from categories in bulk (myql implementation)

Tags: magento2

I am working on developing a functionality where I can bulk remove products from the category by comma-separated SKU list.

It works with the `deleteByIds` method.

```
$this->categoryLinkRepository->deleteByIds(
                $categoryIds,
                $product->getSku()
            );
```

But for more than 10000 products at a time, it does not work & a timeout error appears.

Is there any way we can use MySQL implementation for this of course as di in class?

Comment: https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/ERROR-504-GATEWAY-TIMEOUT/td-p/93817

Comment: Thanks for the comment but i am looking for some answer that has changes in program.

Comment: This issue is a server issue not a program.

Comment: Well we can always optimize code.

Comment: Server is working at its best for magento.

Comment: which server do you have to use for Magento 2??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130680/discussion-between-bhavin-gohil-and-devhs).

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?